# Water softener tank has resin with the salt

Tags: water

I see resin in my salt tank what do I do and what is it from. 99.99% sodium chloride pellets  only I use?

Comment: How old is your softener, roughly?

Answer (score 2):

Water softener resin is supposed to be in the water softener tank, so if it's showing up in the brine tank it came from the water softener, and something is wrong with the control valve for that to happen.

It **should be** a one-way trip for brine, from the brine tank, into the softener tank with the resin to recharge it, and out the drain line after regeneration is complete and the used brine is flushed out with fresh water.

So resin showing up in the brine tank would appear to indicate something not working right, and most of the options for that are in the control valve. New water is sent to the brine tank to make more brine, but there should not be any resin coming out with that water (and if there is, I have to wonder if it's showing up anywhere else in your plumbing you can't see it.)

I don't have a more specific diagnosis than that.